# Trace main functions in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Is there a way to combine both `:main` and `:trace` commands in GHCi? I need to trace an exception in an app that needs input arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's simply `:trace main`.

Do not forget about `:set -fbreak-on-error` and `:set -fbreak-on-exception`.

Comment: I've tried this but GHCi doesn't accept the arguments that I need to pass to the main function e.g. `:main --input test.txt` works well but  `:trace main --input test.txt` doesn't.

Comment: Try using `:set args` then.